# Сортировка массива

Tags: сортировка, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отсортировать данный массив.

```
Array
(
    [Неодеваемые вещи ТН - EF] => Array
        (
            [Боевой перстень Охранницы EF] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Боевой перстень Охранницы
                    [quality] => EF
                    [category] => Неодеваемые вещи ТН
                    [quantity] => 3
                )
    [Неодеваемые вещи ТН - F] => Array
        (
            [Браслеты охранницы F] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Браслеты охранницы
                    [quality] => F
                    [category] => Неодеваемые вещи ТН
                    [quantity] => 1
                )
    [Неодеваемые вещи ТН - VF] => Array
        (
            [Магический шлем Служителя VF] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Магический шлем Служителя
                    [quality] => VF
                    [category] => Неодеваемые вещи ТН
                    [quantity] => 1
                )
    [Неодеваемые вещи ТН - P] => Array
        (
            [Магический шлем Служителя VF] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Магический шлем Служителя
                    [quality] => VF
                    [category] => Неодеваемые вещи ТН
                    [quantity] => 1
                )
)
```

Мне надо, чтобы отсортированный массив был вида

```
[Неодеваемые вещи ТН - EF]
[Неодеваемые вещи ТН - VF]
[Неодеваемые вещи ТН - F]
[Неодеваемые вещи ТН - P]
```

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста момент,можно ли сортировать по определенному индексу массива? например по 'quality'

Comment: Добавил...

Comment: @Женька Сидоров, когда и где можно будет потестировать? :)

Comment: что именно протестировать?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи функции [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php), конечно.

Создаете дополнительную функцию перестановки, которая принимает на вход 
два значения(это будут два элемента сортируемого массива. В вашем случае - тоже массивы),
затем должна выдать ответ:

если первый элемент "меньше", то -1
если первый элемент "больше", то +1
если элементы равны, то 0

> Подскажите еще пожалуйста момент,можно
> ли сортировать по определенному
> индексу массива? например по 'quality'

Да. Но для более точного ответа мне нужно знать: будет ли разное значение у этого параметра, если вещей больше одной внутри подмассива. В любом случае, вам нужно извлечь ключи при помощи `array_keys()`, а потом внутри функции перестановки сравнивать `$a[%cloth_name%]['quality']`, где cloth_name - название шмотки.

Кстати. неНАдеваемые вещи. неОдеваемые могут быть девушки.

Comment: Да но как функция поймет какой порядок мне нужен,она выстроит элементы по своему!

допустим у меня есть массив 

$array = array("VF","EF","P","F");

если отстортирую она мне выдаст

Array
(
    [0] => EF
    [1] => F
    [2] => P
    [3] => VF
)
а мне нужен 
Array
(
    [0] => EF
    [1] => VF
    [2] => F
    [3] => P
)
    [2] => P
    [3] => VF
)

Comment: Создаете массив: $order=>array('EF'=>0,'VF'=>1,'F'=>2,'P'=>3);
Внутри функции перестановки пишете ответ в зависимости от $order[$key1]>$order[$key2], где key1 и key2 - это Неодеваемые вещи ТН - XX

Comment: Вот спасибо,я так и думал что надо создать массив как шаблон для сортировки!

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение,буду пробовать! Просто у меня разные категории шмоток,есть где нужно отсортировать по качеству,есть где по уровню!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
uksort($arr, function($a,$b){
    $a = trim(substr($a,-2));
    $b = trim(substr($b,-2));
    return strcmp($a,$b) ? substr_compare($a,$b,-1) : false;
});
```

**UPD** Для версий PHP 5.2 и ниже:

```
function mySortByKey($a,$b){
    $a = trim(substr($a,-2));
    $b = trim(substr($b,-2));
    return strcmp($a,$b) ? substr_compare($a,$b,-1) : false;
}
uksort($arr,'mySortByKey');
```

Comment: Не такой вариант не работает

Comment: @Женька Сидоров , Странно, вроде как проверил. На phpfiddlу сохранить чего-то не получается, поэтому [выложил пример тут][1]

   [1]:http://codepad.viper-7.com/YDKvET

Comment: Да нет версия 5.3.8

Comment: Посмотрел ваш пример,действительно работает,осталось разобраться в нем!